# How to unit test class properties when the return value is only for the parent

Tags: c#, unit-testing

OK, I couldn't think on how to properly word the question, but an example will clear it up. Suppose I have this class:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subject> Children { get; set; }
}
```

So a subject has a collection of subjects, which in turn can have subjects. And then I have this method. This saves the subject and the subject's children, if any:

```
public int CreateSubject(Subject newSubject)
{
    //...
}
```

Upon creating a subject, the new Id is returned. So in my unit tests for this, I can test if I created a subject by checking the return value to be not zero. Right now, I have a test named that assets for the returned Id:

```
CreateSubject_ValidValues_CreatesSubject
```

but I realized this could have succeeded even if the children weren't saved. I want to have something like:

```
CreateSubject_ValidValuesWithValidChildren_CreatesSubjectAndChildren
```

but I am not sure how I can check if the children were succesfully saved. I am not sure what to assert. How do I test somehitng like this?

Comment: You could assert if the `Children` length is `> 0`

Comment: @12seconds: Can you elaborate? I don't understand, it is > 0 to begin with since I added children, so even if its > 0, I can't be sure that they were saved successfully.

Comment: If you are creating a new object of `Subject`, length of the `Children` is expected to be `0` no? Then you would just check if `Children.Count > 0`. Now if you're talking about if it's saved correctly, this is a different story, now we're talking about integration testing not unit testing.

Comment: When I create the subject, Children will be greater than zero, that's how CreateSubject knows it has children to save. If children were zero, that means there are no child subjects to save. So lets say I want to save a subject with 2 children, I will pass a subject object with 2 children, so it has 2 children to begin with.

Comment: IMHO It would be a ton easier if you were using interfaces, so you could mock an `ISubject` instead of instantiating one.  And a *subject* shouldn't know anything about how to *save* itself.

Comment: Can you please provide full classes.  As it is, it's very difficult to actually answer this answer in the best possible fashion.

Comment: @g_b The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you can't test that `CreateSubject( )` is creating a valid subject unless you have another function that then fetches it by the ID returned.  The useful "unit" to test in this case is not the function `CreateSubject` but whatever unit is responsible for creation/retrieval etc. of Subject objects.